# World Series probability: Assume the probability that Team 1 wins a game over Team 2 is 0.6

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck on the following.  This problem has 4 sub-questions and I want to confirm I'm on the right track or please explain where I'm going wrong for the this last question provided.

World Series probability: Assume the probability that Team 1 wins a game over Team 2 is 0.6.  What is the probability that Team 2 won the World Series over Team 1.  NOTE: 4 to nothing win, 4 to 2, 4 to 3

Since for the other problems, Team 1 was favored...p = 0.6 and q = 1-0.6 = 0.4.

So I calculated this problem as such:
1) 4 to nothing: C(4,0)p * q * p = 24 * 0.4 * 0.6 * 0.4 = 2.304

2) 4 to 2: C(5,3)p^3 * q^2 * p = 10 * 0.4^3 * 0.6^2 * 0.4 = 10 * 0.064 * 0.36 * 0.4 = 0.09216

3) 4 to 3: C(6,3)p^4 * q^3 * p = 20 * 0.0256 * 0.216 * 0.4 = 0.0442368

Your assistance is greatly appreciated!  Please keep it in this format since this is how I learned it and I don't want to get confused.  Thank you!!

Comment: The strategy here is good. You seemed to miss one case: 4 to 1. I would frame these outcomes as winning the series in 4 games, 5 games, 6 games, or 7 games. (Also, check your first computation: probabilities cannot exceed 1.)

Comment: A useful trick for problems like this is to imagine that all $7$ games are played, even though a winner may be decided before the last game.  Team $2$ wins iff they win $4$ or more games out of the $7$.

Comment: Thank you guys! For the 4 game win, I recalculated it and I got C(4,0)p^4 * q^0 = 24 * 0.4^4 * 0.6^0 = 24 * 0.0256 * 1 = 0.6144.  For the 5 game win (4 to 1): C(4,1)p^4 * q^1 * p = 24 * 0.0256 * 0.06 * 0.4 = 0.147456.  Are my calculations correct?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to calculate:

a) 4 or more wins out of 7 =$\sum_{k=4}^7\binom{7}{k} 0.4^k0.6^{7-k}$

b) 4 wins out of games played $\sum_{n=4}^7 \binom{n}{4} 0.4^4 0.6^{n-4}$.